# What is the type of a jQuery object in TypeScript?

Tags: jquery, typescript, types

What type I should use for jQuery elements?

Without jQuery I go on like this:

```typescript
export class Modal {
    constructor(protected element:HTMLElement) {
    }
}
```

But, lets say `element` will be a jQuery selector like `$('.myDiv')` for example. What type should `element` then have?

Comment: Why not install the [typing for jQuery](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jquery.TypeScript.DefinitelyTyped/)?

Comment: Yes, why not? Did not even know it existed. Thanks!

Comment: @RamblinRose Hm, that dit not go too well. I get this error when i compile the project: "TypeScript error: node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2362,84): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'."

Answer (score 31):

After installing the types needed (`npm install --save-dev @types/jquery`), you can type it as just `JQuery`:

```
constructor(protected element: JQuery) {

}
```

Comment: I did install it but it keeps giving me this error: "TypeScript error: node_modules/@types/jquery/index.d.ts(2362,84): Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Iterable'."

Comment: Post your `tsconfig.json`. You are most probably missing `"lib" : ["es2015"]` in your `tsconfig.json`

Comment: Actually i dont have any tsconfig.json at all since im using the gulp-version. My gulp task(s) looks like this: https://pastebin.com/waAXgbAr