# How to import jQuery with TypeScript so that I can set it as a type for a property

Tags: jquery, typescript, phpstorm

I use `jQuery` in my TypeScript project. I had `npm install --save-dev @types/jquery` before. And in my file I have `import $ from 'jquery';` then I have class:

```
class A {
  $el: $
}
```

And PhpStorm produces the error `Cannot find name $`. However if I use jQuery as a constructor like `$('selector')` no error occurred.

`tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": ["es2018", "dom"],
    "baseUrl": "./src2",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ],
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ]
  }
```

I tried import `jQuery` also like this `import * as $ from 'jquery'`, `import $ = require('jquery');`.

`jQuery` version: `3.3.1`.

Comment: Did you do npm install jquery as well?

Comment: @Ric yes, I did

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/a/44605876/885626 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/13153423/885626

Comment: @Ric works! I have been searching the answer for an hour and have not found this post. Most likely it does not contain search keywords I searched for.

Comment: @Ric you can answer with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `JQuery` object type instead of `$` for variable/property assignment as per answer here

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13153423/885626